# PHP PostgreSQL check if update query was successful

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I'm using a PSQL database with PHP to do an update query. I have to check if the query was successful or not. I tried the MySQL 'version' like this but it doesn't work and I always get the `echo 'error';`:

```
public function update_user($psql, $data) {
    $update = pg_fetch_all(pg_query_params($psql, "UPDATE users SET first_name = $1, last_name = $2, email = $3 WHERE id = $4", array($data['first_name'], $data['last_name'], $data['email'], $data['user_id'])));
    if ($update) {
        echo 'succes';
    }
    else {
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pg_query_params`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) returns a value described as:

> A query result resource on success or FALSE on failure.

So just check that return value for falseness.

Also since your update query does not return any row, even when it succeeds there's no point in passing its return value to `pg_fetch_all`. Not being `false` is all that matters.